Why is the bitcoin tag not allowed?
If the question is related to Bitcoin and not altcoin then the bitcoin tag should be allowed, since questions related to altcoins are allowed on bitcoin SE it is not redundant to specify.

The vast majority of questions here are about Bitcoin as the title of the site suggests, so the absence of the altcoins tags is enough to assume the question is about bitcoin

Exactly. A tag that would be on 80% of the questions would not do anything to specify a topic.
